# MySQL can't import database (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to **import** the database from server to my system. But this error displayed :

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'chee.address_format' (errno: 150)
```

I know this is because foreign key and records not now to be constructed !
Can you help me?

Comment: Can you show us what tables are available in the database? And the query you are using to create this table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily disable a foreign key constraint using this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

And import again, and do not forget to do

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: I try this, And this error displayed : #1193 - Unknown system variable 'FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKES'

Comment: Oh, i made a mistake... Try this instead : SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;